# How do I supress the #lines in a Results drawer to have only the answer

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, org-mode

Win10:Emacs 25.2.1:Org 9.4.4
I am running this test source block from ob-ipython Git page:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session mysession :exports both :results raw
  def foo(x):
      return x + 9
  [foo(x) + 7 for x in range(7)]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
# Out[2]:
# text/plain
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```

I cannot find a way to suppress the # Out[] and # text/plain lines. I only want the raw data but all the options I have tried still show these two lines in the result. I have searched for an answer but have yet to see someone else's output that looks like this. Any suggestions to supress these lines?

Comment: Is using the regular `python` interpreter instead of `ipython` an option?

Comment: iPython would be nice because it neatly places the image following the code block . Regular python creates an image link that I have to manually insert following the source block.I am using J.Kitchin's scimax version as the front end for emacs. I have not upgraded past Ver 25.x yet as I am finishing a major document for publication and I dont want to touch what works. I was hoping to hear if ver 26+ acted differently.